# Image Classifire feature detector

Tags: python, opencv, python-descriptors

I have a code that I learn from this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nnH55-zD38I&t=1047s
but I got an error that said:

```
line 62, in <module>
    cv2.putText(imgOriginal,classNames[id], (50,50),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),1)
IndexError: list index out of range
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-m8us58q4\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp 
(438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
import os

path = '#2 Image descriptor\Assets\Query'
orb = cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=1000)

#IMPORT IMAGES 
images = []
classNames = []
myList = os.listdir(path)
print('Jumlah Classes = ', len(myList))
#print(myList)
for cl in myList:
    imgCur = cv2.imread(f'{path}/{cl}', 0)
    images.append(imgCur)
    classNames.append(os.path.splitext(cl)[0])
print (classNames)
   
def findDes(images) :
    desList = []
    for img in images :
        kp, des = orb.detectAndCompute(img, None)
        desList.append(des)
    return desList

def findID(img, desList, thres=15):
    kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img, None)
    bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
    matchList = []
    finalVal = -1
    try :
        for des in desList:
            matches = bf.knnMatch(des, des2, k=2)
            good = []
            for m, n in matches:
                if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
                    good.append([m])
                matchList.append(len(good))
    except :
        pass
    #print(matchList)
    if len(matchList) != 0:
        if max(matchList) > thres:
            finalVal = matchList.index(max(matchList))
    return finalVal

desList = findDes(images)
print(len(desList))

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#cap = cv2.imread('#2 Image descriptor\Assets\Train\RE8.jpg')

while True:

    success, img2 = cap.read()
    imgOriginal = img2.copy()
    img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    id = findID(img2, desList)
    if id != -1:
        cv2.putText(imgOriginal,classNames[id], (50,50),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),1)

    cv2.imshow('img2', imgOriginal)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break 

cap.release() #to make sure disable the camera from the code
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

I think the error at:

```
imgCur = cv2.imread(f'{path}/{cl}', 0)
```

Comment: Please provide more details on what should be expected and why do you think the specified statement (line 15) is the source of the error.

Comment: so the code is should be showing what object it is by matching the images in query file. then while i tried to run the code, when i showing the exact same object to cam, the cam is close suddenly, then show the error. i change line 15 by deleting the "f" the cam is not closed, but the program not showing the name of the object it is :)
btw, sorry im new in this field. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at this part of your code:

```
    if id != -1:
        cv2.putText(imgOriginal,classNames[id], (50,50),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),1)
```

The error is basically telling you that you are trying to index `id` from the `classNames` list at an index that doesn't exist in the list. For example, if the `classNames` list is empty, doing `classNames[0]` will return the error. You can try debugging like so:

```
    if id != -1:
        if id < len(classNames):
            cv2.putText(imgOriginal,classNames[id], (50,50),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),1)
        else:
            print(classNames)
            print(f"Error: Attempted to index {id} from list of length {len(classNames)}.")
```

Comment: now it show this :

`Error: Attempted to index 945 from list 
of length 3.`

what should i do next ? :D

Comment: @AlficoPermana I believe you'll have to look into your `findID` function, see if there are any bugs you missed.